# How do I get my desktop shortcuts from disappearing?

Tags: 16.04

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu and I've been having a problem where my desktop (not the hot bar) has the shortcuts gone and am unable to right click to bring up the menu. Only solution I know of is to restart my machine. I've tried to google it but nothing appears or is unanswered.

Comment: What Ubuntu version? Have you installed some file manager?

Comment: That used to happen to me all the time. Upgrading to Kernel 4.7.5 along with other tweaks made it go away for the most part. After chrome corruption today when I rebooted it got stuck on `Thermald shutting down` for 1 minute and had to hard power off the machine. The nextst boot came up with black desktop and no icons I immediately rebooted and normal desktop popped. Also on older kernel versions (4.4 that came with Ubuntu 16.04) unplugging my USB self-powered hub before booting helped out. Although I'm not happy about it happening today for the first time in a week  it's better than before :)

Comment: ps It's not called a "hot bar" it's called the `Launcher`. Also if you have your wallpaper recycling I believe you'll find the next time it refreshes (if you can wait that long) the icons will reappear with the wallpaper. You didn't mention if your screen was all black with no wallpaper like it happened to me though.

Comment: It sounds like Nautilus (your File Manager) is crashing or quitting on you. Short term, you can click once on the `Files` icon in the launcher to bring it all back. Long term, you need to review your /var/log/syslog to look for error messages about nautilus crashing, and fix that problem. Cheers, Al

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix sometimes the wallpaper goes back to the default wallpaper

Comment: @CelticWarrior I'm using xenial, and i'm still using the default nautilus file manager.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I think I only had the problem with the black desktop and no icons after rebooting once when i was having problems installing nvidia proprietary drivers. but since then i did a fresh partition and install and re did everything and haven't had that problem. The wallpaper will either go back to default or stay there. but I can't right click on the desktop nor can I see any icons.

Comment: @heynnema I'll check the /var/log/syslog and see if that's the case

Comment: @DanielHorn Please do check. The reason for my question and heynnema's suggestion is the same. The file manager is the one is charge of what happens or not in your desktop therefore installing a new one could have messed something but since you didn't then the default one is probably crashing so it's better to check the logs and try to find the cause there.

Comment: @DanielHorn does clicking on the Files icon in the launcher bring back the desktop? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema i'll check that next time it happens. I'll get back to you next time.

Comment: @celticwarrior does the syslog wipe everytime you restart?

Comment: No, the syslog is cumulative. After the main syslog file starts to get too big, the system creates a compressed copies of the syslog file and calls them syslog.1 _(the first copy is not compressed)_, syslog.2.gz, syslog.3.gz, etc. To search for nautilus related messages, in terminal, you'd type **grep -i nautilus /var/log/syslog***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Nautilus *(your File Manager)* is crashing or quitting on you. Have you added any nautilus extensions or scripts that might be causing this? **Short term**, you can click once on the `Files` icon in the launcher to bring it all back. **Long term**, you need to review your /var/log/syslog to look for error messages about nautilus crashing, and fix that problem.

To review your syslog, and search for nautilus related messages, in terminal, you'd type:

**grep -i nautilus /var/log/syslog***

Comment: Alright, so it happened again and clicked on the nautilus icon on the launch bar, and the desktop icons showed right up. I checked the log, how would I go about posting it?

Comment: OK, so we're on the right path. Since the output of my grep command is probably pretty small, just edit your question and add it there. If it is a lot of text, go to paste.ubuntu.com and put it there, and give us the URL so that we can take a look at it. Have you ever added any Nautilus extensions or scripts to your computer? Add the output of **dpkg -l \*nautilus\*** to your edit (that's a lower case L). Cheers, Al